# NodeJS: How to send entity from mysql to rabbitmq

Tags: mysql, node.js, rabbitmq

I'm trying to send an "entity" obtained from MySQL to RabbitMQ.

I'm able to make the connection to the database and return data. Example:

```
    dbConnection.query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE Id = ?", customerId, (err, rows, fields) => {
    ...
    res.status(200).json(rows)
    ...
    }
```

After this I am able to watch in Postman the "JSON result", so, I want to send this "JSON result" as an string to RabbitMQ.

I can send to RabbitMq a fake data object with no problem:

```
    const fakeData = {
        name: "Elon Musk",
        company: "SpaceX",
    };

    channel.sendToQueue("message-queue", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(fakeData)));
```

So, how must I convert the "rows" object returned from MySQL to send it to the queue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is as follows:

```js
rows.forEach(function (row) {
    channel.sendToQueue("message-queue", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(row)));
});
```